# React Native Expo Realm template not working

Tags: react-native, expo, realm

I am trying to learn React Native with Realm.

I installed the default template with:

```
npx create-react-native-app --template with-realm ExpoRealm
```

Then I tried to run it with:

```
npx expo run:android
```

It fails with the following error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR: ExpoRealm/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/splashscreen.xml:3: AAPT: error: resource color/splashscreen_background (aka com.anonymous.exporealm:color/splashscreen_background) not found.
```

Help please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Those may be the incorrect steps. The template is installed like this `npx create-expo-app AtlasDeviceSdkApp --template @realm/expo-template`. Going through the [Getting Started Guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/install/) would probably help. Ensure you go through the [Bootstrap with Expo - React Native SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/bootstrap-with-expo/) section as that's specific to Expo